# Cakephp crashing on php error

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp

Whenever there's an error in my code cakephp crashes without returning any debug information.

the response I get is:

> Erro 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): the server closed the connection without sending any data

I'm running cakephp 2.3.6 on a Mac with XAMPP

on core.php there's:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

and

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'trace' => true
));
```

I thought it was a problem with xampp or my vhost configuration but:

- I've recently formated my computer and I'm getting the same error;
- I just tried replacing the all cake app with a test page and errors are showing.

I can see the errors on APP/tmp/logs/error.log but not on screen. An example:

```
2013-07-03 18:23:15 Error: Fatal Error (4): syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in [/Users/fimdomeio/Sites/e-studio.dev/View/News/admin_edit.ctp, line 37]
2013-07-03 18:23:15 Error: [FatalErrorException] syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'
Request URL: /admin/news/edit/1
Stack Trace:
#0 /Users/fimdomeio/Sites/cakephp2.3.6/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(184): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(4, 'syntax error, u...', '/Users/fimdomei...', 37)
#1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(4, 'syntax error, u...', '/Users/fimdomei...', 37, Array)
#2 /Users/fimdomeio/Sites/cakephp2.3.6/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(927): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 4, 'syntax error, u...', '/Users/fimdomei...', 37, Array)
#3 /Users/fimdomeio/Sites/cakephp2.3.6/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(900): App::_checkFatalError()
#4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
#5 {main}
```

Comment: Have you tried it from different browsers? Do you have the same response?

Comment: Yes I've tried from different browsers. Currently the only way to get the errors is from CAKE_APP_DIR/tmp/error.log

Comment: @fimdomeio It might be a brilliant idea to paste the errors you see there here? Also check the php and webserver logs. This comes mostly up when the server, php or a module crashes.

Comment: burnzum: there's nothing really relevant about the errors... They're just the usual stuff... missing a semicolon here a ending brace there. I'm going to post the error just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: If that is your "usual stuff" your code is crap... Check the first two errors these are fatal errors, syntax errors. Fix them and see if its going to work then. Cake should catch these errors and display an error page but some modules, webservers or memory limit for example can cause the server to not respond with anything and in the worst case result in a crash of a module or the whole webserver. Best practice is to not even have notices in coming up from your code by the way, because even a notice has a meaning and reason.

Comment: @burzum, you're completly missing the point. It's obvious that all errors and notices should be fixed. My problem is that errors are not being output to screen as I would expect when developing the app, and that makes debugging a lot more time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the the php error_reporting variable is set to on - it will be in your php.ini or .htacces file

Comment: error_reporting seems to be On:

    error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  |  
    display_errors = on  |  
    display_startup_errors = On  |  
    log_errors = Off  |  
    log_errors_max_len = 1024  |  
    ignore_repeated_errors = Off  |  
    ignore_repeated_source = Off  |  
    report_memleaks = On  |  
    track_errors = Off  |  
    error_log = syslog

Comment: also htaccess does not mension anything about errors only the defult redirect rules from cakephp